# Почему javascript код не работает после определенной строки?

Tags: javascript

```js
//Modal windows

function Modal(modalBlock, buttonClick, buttonClose) {
 this.modalBlock = document.querySelector(modalBlock);
 this.buttonClick =  document.querySelector(buttonClick);
 this.modalClose = document.querySelector(buttonClose);
 this.currentClass = this.modalBlock.getAttribute('class');

 this.buttonClick.onclick = () => {

  if (this.modalBlock.classList.contains(this.currentClass + '--active-js') == false) {
   this.modalBlock.classList.add(this.currentClass + '--active-js')
  }
 }

 this.modalClose.onclick = () => {

  if (this.modalBlock.classList.contains(this.currentClass + '--active-js') == true) {
   this.modalBlock.classList.remove(this.currentClass + '--active-js');
  }
 }

 this.modalBlock.onclick = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  var contentCurrentClass = this.currentClass;
  if (event.target.classList.contains(contentCurrentClass + '--active-js') == true) {
   this.modalBlock.classList.remove(contentCurrentClass + '--active-js');
  }
 }
}

var videoModal = new Modal('.modal-wrapper', '.play-video', '.modal__close');
var appModal = new Modal('.modal-wrapper', '.button', '.modal__close');
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.125rem 0;
  min-width: 15.625rem;
  background-color: #9e784c;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.875rem #9e784c;
          box-shadow: 0 0 0.875rem #9e784c;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.button:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1.75rem #9e784c;
          box-shadow: 0 0 1.75rem #9e784c;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-wrapper--active-js {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: modalShow 1s 1;
          animation: modalShow 1s 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.modal {
  width: 70%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1.25rem;
}
.modal__video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}
.modal__name {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
}
.modal__title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: block;
  color: #828282;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.modal__title--contacts-flat {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}
.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -26px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
.modal__close--application {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
}
.modal--form {
  padding: 0;
}
.modal__background {
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(../img/form_background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
.modal__form-place {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal__headline {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  color: #333333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #828282;
  width: 74%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.modal__sub-title {
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 4.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44%;
}
.modal__input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 2.5rem auto;
  padding: 8px 26px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9e784c;
}
.modal__input--user {
  background-image: url(../img/1.png);
  background-position: 6px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.modal__input--phone {
  background-image: url(../img/2.png);
  background-position: 6px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button button-openform--js">Заказать звонок</a>
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div class="modal modal--form">
                <div class="modal__background">
                    <h4 class="modal__title modal__title--contacts-flat">
                        жк «Достояние»
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal__form-place">
                    <h5 class="modal__headline">
                        Обратный звонок
                    </h5>
                    <span class="modal__sub-title">
                        оставьте заявку и мы вам перезвоним
                    </span>
                    <div class="modal__form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="ВВЕДИТЕ ИМЯ" class="modal__input modal__input--user">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" class="modal__input modal__input--phone">
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="button" id='send-form'>Заказать звонок</a>
                </div>
                <span class="modal__close modal__close--application">
                    закрыть
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

P.S. Если две последние строчки поменять местами, то все работает как нужно.

По какой причине такое может быть?

Хотя код до этой строчки (И включая эту строчку) отлично работает.

Comment: "отлично работает" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: И даже в js-консоли никаких ошибок нет?

Comment: @Igor, проверил в верстке, код должен скрывать и показывать модальное окно, он с этим справляется, на другой странице вызывать модальное окно надо на другую кнопку, но этого не происходит (За это отвечает второй объект), выскакивает ошибка, что modalBlock - null, но это не так, ведь элемент 100% есть на странице, а самое интересное, что если alert поставить перед этой строчкой, то и он отрабатывает как надо. А если после этой строчки, то он не работает, если строчки поменять местами, то на второй странице будет работать вызов, а на первой - нет

Comment: сделай [mcve] воспроизводящий ошибку. Добавь в сниппет разметку

Comment: @andreymal, выше описал проблему подробнее

Comment: @Grundy, добавил пример, если последние строчки местами поменять, то работает, а так - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит `Modal` надо написать так, чтобы он ничего не делал, если на странице чего-то не хватает.

```
function Modal(modalBlock, buttonClick, buttonClose) {
  this.modalBlock = document.querySelector(modalBlock);
  this.buttonClick =  document.querySelector(buttonClick);
  this.modalClose = document.querySelector(buttonClose);

  this.ready = this.modalBlock && this.buttonClick && this.modalClose;

  if (!this.ready)
    return;

  ...
```